# Sort results alphabetically in a recursive function

Tags: php

I was obliged to use a recursive function to fill a drop down list, however, when I tried to display results in alphabetical order using `ORDER BY` it didn't work!
Below is my recursive function:

```
function tree($root) { 
  global $conn;
  $n=0;
  $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM personne WHERE emp_id='$root' ORDER BY name"); 
  $result->execute();
  while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $n = $n+1;
    echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</option>"; 
    tree($row['id'], $n+1); 
  }   
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: You're calling your function from inside itself with a second parameter `$n+1` but you don't have that parameter in your function

Comment: P.S. What didn't work? What happened and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @elgonzo is it a problem?

Comment: @JonathonHenderson the ORDER BY doesn't work.
I get names but not in aplphabetcal order

Comment: You pass two arguments `tree($row['id'], $n+1);` where the function only defines one

Comment: `PDO::FETC_ASSOC` wrong spelling

Comment: @JonathonHenderson it just a mistake when copying code

Comment: It's very inefficient to repeatedly do the same query where you need only do it once. As mentioned before, you're trying to call your function with 2 parameters but it only accepts one.. Try moving `$n=0` into your parameters i.e.g `function tree($root, $n=0)`

Comment: Of course the ORDER BY works – for each _individual_ query. But since you are making queries recursively, that has no effect on the _end_ result – that should be quite obvious. So collect your data first, in an array f.e., and then sort it afterwards.

Comment: If this is meant to be recursive you will need to have a value for each item, referencing to a parent item e.g `parent_id`